# On duplicate key based on two columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm having a bit of trouble with my java app,either i don't know enough or this isn't possible in a simple manner.I'm hoping it is the first option since i'm a beginner.

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evolution` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` double NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `operator` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to keep track of some product sales by their date.

What i'd like to achieve is this : lets say the operator enters today, `17.01.2014` the product `banana` with the quantity `4`.Later that day he will insert `apples` with the quantity `10`.The same day he will insert `banana` with the quantity `1` and `apples` with the quantity `12`.

Tomorrow he will do the same,insert `bananas` with the quantity `2` but on the date `18.01.2014`.This should be on a new row since its the same product but on a different date.

In this situation, i need my database to do the following :
Check if `banana` was inserted on `17.01.2014`.If not, insert it with the quantity `0+4`.
If banana was already inserted on `17.01.2014` update the quantity `4+1`.

The next day it will check if `banana` was inserted on `18.01.2014`.If not,insert it with the quantity `2`.If yes,update the quantity.

So : i can't have any of the columns unique since the date can be the same for`apples` and `banana` and the same for the date and of course,quantity.

How can i achieve this ?
I thought about a couple of ways but it isn't very efficient:

1. `Select (product,date) from evolution where product=banana AND date=18.01.2014`
   If this returns anything then i will execute an update.
   If this doesn't return anything then i will execute an insert.
2. Make a column `product-date`  that will be unique. In it i will insert for example `banana 17.01.2014`.This would be easier but i don't like this way,its dirty.

All this would be so easy if i could do something like a double on duplicate key.Try and insert `banana and date`.Then,if the combination already exist,do an update.

To make it shorter and easier to understand:

This is valid :

```
+-------+----------+
|product|date      |
+-------+----------+
|banana |17.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
|banana |18.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
|apples |17.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
|apples |18.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
```

This is NOT valid :

```
+-------+----------+
|product|date      |
+-------+----------+
|banana |17.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
|banana |17.01 2014|
+-------+----------+
|banana |18.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
|banana |18.01.2014|
+-------+----------+
```

So they(`product` and `date`) can have duplicates by themselves but not together.

Sorry for the long post...i hope i'm not missing any easy and clean way of doing this but i just might and i sure hope so,i'm a beginner in programming.
Thanks and have a good night !

Comment: Have a unique key on (product,date) !?!?!

Comment: Seems like you're after a unique constraint of product and date. Can add it after the fact or make it part of the create table statement. Doing it after would look like this: `ALTER TABLE evolution 
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_product UNIQUE (product,date)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you want a composite key on product AND date.

```
PRIMARY KEY (product, date)
```

Composite primary keys are essentially a way to determine a thing's uniqueness using more than one key.  For example, if you had a store that sold only hammers and nails that were both blue or red, you couldn't identify those in the db as hammer or blue, you'd have to use both

```
tool  |  color |  quantity
hammer   blue     4
hammer   red      3 
nail     blue     1 
nail     red      6
```

your PK here would be on tool and color.

Comment: Didn't knew about that, about composite keys, i will have to research and get back here :D

Comment: Would it be id & date or product & date?

Comment: @MagicMan good catch.  product.  I didn't read the question well enough to see that banana != id.  Thought because he labeled his PK as id that is what banana was.  Thank you btw

Comment: Yes,this is exactly what i needed,sorry for wasting your time with such a silly question...the restrictions of learning...Thanks a lot, Brad!

Comment: Oh, yea, sure, i accidentally pressed the up vote and thought i accepted it as well, my bad. Again, thanks and sorry for wasting your time twice, heh.